# Is it possible to generate a new self-signed certificate from an existing private key with powershell?

Tags: powershell, certificate, pki, self-signed-certificate

I tried:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -ExistingKey "c:\cts_privkey.pem" -Container localhost -Provider "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES cryptographic Provider" -DnsName "example.com" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My"
```

[image]

I don't think I am using the command correctly.
Can this eve

Comment: You are missing -CertStoreLocation parameter.  "When you use an existing key, specify values for the Container parameter, the Provider parameter, and the CertStoreLocation parameter. CertStoreLocation determines the context. The context is user or computer."   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=windowsserver2019-ps

Comment: @Daniel I added the CertStoreLocation, the error remained the same. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @tks.tman key container names usually have trailing GUID's or version identifiers, are you sure `localhost` is right? You can get the existing container name by inspecting the certificate associated with it: `(Get-Item Cert:\LocalMachine\My\<certID>).PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo`